# How do I remove the first 30 charicters in each line from a CMD dir command, and execute a script write for each in javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, command-line

I'm looking at building a command that can take in the dir list from a cmd and dump out a list of commands to be executed, but can only have the code able to work on the first line. What do I need to do in order to have it work on all of the lines?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            drive:<br>
            <input type=text>
        </p>
        list:<br>
        <textarea onchange="myFunction(this.value)"></textarea>
            <div id='output'>
            </div>

        <script>
            function myFunction(val)
            {
                val = val.toLowerCase(); //new object assigned to var str
                val = val.substring(30);
                val = val.replace(/_/g, "");

                val = val.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = val;
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

input data:

```
07/05/2017  02:56 PM                    sample1
07/06/2017  02:12 AM                    sample2
07/05/2017  06:09 PM                    sample3
07/05/2017  07:20 PM                    sample4
07/05/2017  10:59 PM                    sample5
07/05/2017  10:54 AM                    sample6
07/06/2017  05:44 AM                    sample7
```

output sample:

```
samplecheck.exe E:\sample1  >E:\sample1.txt
samplecheck.exe E:\sample2  >E:\sample2.txt
samplecheck.exe E:\sample3  >E:\sample3.txt
samplecheck.exe E:\sample4  >E:\sample4.txt
```

Comment: You need to split the string into an array of smaller strings on the `\n` (line feed) character.  `var arr = val.split("\n");`, iterate the array, and operate on each element.

Comment: @James can you make an example of this?

Comment: It might simplify things to use `dir /b` so that the date, time, and size aren't shown.

Comment: nope, i need it to go line by line for many folders (100+)

Answer (score 0):

Removing characters from the beginning of a set of filenames can be done using a quirk in the way Dos works with spaces on the command line. first replacing the unwanted characters with spaces, and then dropping the spaces using a FOR...IN...DO construction. Whatever the actual length of the filenames, handling of long filenames by FOR must be enabled with LFNFOR On so that the spaces can be accepted as part of the filenames.

Example:

To remove the first two characters from the beginning of all filenames in the current directory: 
REN *.* " *.*" 
LFNFOR On 
FOR %v IN (*.*) DO REN "%v" %v

Comment: I know the fixed length at the beginning of the file name, and can scrub off any excess, so this answer doesn't help at all. I run a lot of these scripts,